# A New Analytic Inequality 

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Consider an analytic function $f : U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $U$ is an open subset of the complex numbers which contains the closed unit disk. I have $|f(x)| \geq 1$ for any $ x \in [-1, 1]$. Is the following true ? 
$$ |\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\overline{f(e^{-it})}dt| \geq 4$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\overline{f(e^{-it})}dt= |f(0)|^2,$$
as you can check applying the Cauchy formula to the holomorphic function $f(z)\overline{f(\bar z)}$.